# Unable to run a .NET6 container image in AWS lambda

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile

I am trying to run a .NET6 image in AWS lambda and it is failing with error:

*{
"errorMessage": "RequestId: 5aca05-***** Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason", "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError"
}*

I am unable to understand why it is failing.
I have used the following command to generate the package of dotnet:
`dotnet publish  --configuration Release --framework net6.0 --self-contained true --output output --runtime linux-x64`

Then I am using docker to create the image and updated in ECR.The aws lambda is giving me above error.

The Dockerfile is following:

```
ARG BRANCH_VERSION=latest
FROM allimages.docker.****.*****.com/*****/***-al2:${BRANCH_VERSION}

COPY output /var/task
COPY entrypoint.sh /var/task
RUN chmod 755 /var/task/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/var/task/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["LambdaAwsCore::LambdaAwsCore.Function::FunctionHandler"]
```

The base image is a common private image which does not have dotnet in it.
The entrypoint.sh script will include kerberos later but as of now it is just simple.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "Startup ${@}"
```

I have tried several things but it does not work. When I use AWS dotnet-6 image then it works but without providing entrypoint. I am not sure why when I am adding the entrypoint it does not work.
Please help. I have never used C# in AWS lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue. There were few changes that I had to do.

1. Since I am using a container image with the entrypoint. I had to change the code to executable and then instead  of using the format of CMD where we have [AssemblyName::Namespace.Class::FunctionHandler], i had to change it to [./AssemblyName].
2. Also i added a line to ensure that the handler is called as part of Function.cs(the file have lambda code).

Comment: Care to share the updated Dockerfile?